# What is the difference between `sys.meta_path` and `sys.path_hooks` importer objects?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Using `importlib`, what is the difference between "Meta Path Finder" (found by traversing over sys.meta_path) and Path Entry Finder" (found by traversing over sys.path_hooks)?

The first type is called upon begin of an import, but when is the second type used? Do both return a spec object?

I want to implement a customized import, where a module can be imported from sources other than *.py or *.pyc, e.g. from a stream. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sys.path_hooks [returns a finder factory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path_hooks).

> Path hooks are called as part of sys.path (or `package.__path__` ) processing

as we read in [PEP 302 relevant part](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#specification-part-2-registering-hooks) which you should read to do what you want.

Coming to speak of, we use a [custom hook](https://github.com/wrye-bash/wrye-bash/blob/8627c425d93e4078f41ad104c5216e56cc9b6ad3/Mopy/Wrye%20Bash%20Launcher.pyw) in my code but I would not recommend you to copy it verbatim (I am really not sure about the hocus pocus we do with init files)

However the process is a bit like in there - the `find_module` method returns self or None depending on what you want to accept as a module and the `load_module` method proceeds to load that by compiling the code and assigning it an entry into `sys.modules`. By replacing those parts you can pretty much load whatever you want.

Related:

- [Package-specific import hooks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7268643/281545)
- [Python sys.path_hooks Examples](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/2197/sys.path_hooks)

Comment: I continued and have a more specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990169/how-is-python-sys-path-hooks-used-correctly-for-customized-loading-of-modules

Answer (score 22):

When a module is to be imported, the interpreter first walks through the list of objects in `sys.meta_path`, calling the `find_spec()` or (deprecated since 3.4) `find_module()` method on each. )The interface is documented in the  [importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder) abstract base class.) These are queried before any other importers (including frozen and built-in) are checked and so can override any other import processing.

The `PathFinder` object in `sys.meta_path` is what uses `sys.path` and `sys.path_hooks`. (Except in Python < 3.4 where the `PathFinder` functionality is built in to the interpreter to be used when nothing in `sys.meta_path` can load a module.)

The `PathFinder` walks through the list of paths in `sys.path`. For each path, if [finder](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-finder) is not already  cached for that path in `sys.path_importer_cache` it walks through the list of callables in `sys.path_hooks`, calling each one with the path to see if it will produce a finder; it caches the first one it finds in `sys.path.importer_cache_`.

Once it's got the finder it queries that via the `find_spec()` or deprecated `find_module()` method to see if it can find that module. If so, it can continue on to import it, otherwise it starts the step above with the next path on `sys.path`.

This was initially described in [PEP 302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/), but [PEP 451](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0451/) is pretty much the modern behaviour; the [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) documentation appears to be the current spec.

There's considerably more detail summarized (with more links) in my [personal notes](https://github.com/0cjs/sedoc/blob/master/lang/python/importers.md).